# TypeError: plot_partial_dependence() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kind'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Does anyone know how this code:

```
from sklearn.inspection import plot_partial_dependence


X=df.drop("heart_attack", axis=1)
y=df["heart_attack"]

for i in range(25):
    features= [i]
    plot_partial_dependence(model_reg, X, features, kind='both')
```

causes this Error

```
TypeError: plot_partial_dependence() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kind'
```

I pretty much copied this of the documentation from scikit_learn on ICE and PDP here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/partial_dependence.html. It work if I don't use `kind` as an attribute but I want to use an ICE plot.

Comment: What version of `sklearn` are you using? Apparently the `kind` parameter was added in 0.24.

Comment: Thank you so much this was my problem. I didn't even realize I was running an outdated version of sklearn